# How to make current cell in column C according to value of the cell in A

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

This is very confusing to explain so please excuse if I don't explain well enough.

In column A have Person name.
in Column C is where formula goes.

```
if cell A2:A10 start with letter Q then c2:c10 will be = E2:E10

if cell A11:A20 start with letter B then c11:c20 will be = G2:G10
```

**QData & Bdata is random column Lenth**

I tried writting 1 line formula but it didn't work.

in c2  and drag formula down

```
=if(left(a2,1)="Q",O2,if(left(a2,1)="B",P2,"mORE IF COND"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi buddy) Screen of your worksheet will be much more helpful)

Comment: Unless a2:a10 will NEVER have a B you cannot use a combined if. This gets more and more complicated the more conditions you have. Be sure this is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't post it any earlier.

Comment: @Mowgli +1 for non-trivial quest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the input correctly - you need smth like this:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Q",INDIRECT("O"&ROW(A2)),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="B",INDIRECT("P"&ROW(A2)),A2))
```

Please add instead of `A2` any output you like if cells in A match neither "Q" nor "B".

**EDITED** Update as per changed reqs:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Q",INDIRECT("O"&ROW(A2)),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="B",INDIRECT("P"&(1+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,"Boy"))),A2))
```

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/izrjcvgix752klw/QueenBoyIF.xlsx

Comment: If you need **only** as displayed - this should work: `=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="Q",INDIRECT("O"&ROW(A2)),IF(LEFT(A2,1)="B",INDIRECT("P"&(ROW(A2)-9)),A2))` - adjust `(ROW(A2)-9)` according to your actual sheet if required.

Comment: That was just example, QData and Bdata is random length

Comment: @Mowgli you'd better specify that in you initial request buddy - to avoid confusions.

Comment: @Mowgli do you have only 2 values in A? Are they sorted - or also randomly appearing?

Comment: For this example I have 2 names and 2 data column for those 2 names and they are sorted(column A).

Comment: BRILLIANT WORK!!!! Man I was giving up and was working on alternate solution. thanks alot.

Comment: @Mowgli glad to help buddy - get back soon with new nice Qs! Good luck)